# How to mock localStorage that works with Object.keys(localStorage)?

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

I am able to mock the basic localStorage in jest test like this:

```
// localStorage.js    
export default new class {
    store = {};
    setItem = (key, val) => (this.store[key] = val);
    getItem = key => this.store[key];
    removeItem = key => { delete this.store[key]; };
    clear = () => (this.store = {});
}();

// xxx.test.js
import localStorage from './localStorage';
window.localStorage = localStorage;
```

However, it won't work for mocking something like `Object.keys(localStorage)`, which is supposed to return the keys in the localStorage in an array. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When you have `Object.keys(localStorage)` to iterate through all available keys you can use spying instead of mocking using the following approach. Make sure you call `mockRestore` afterwards (not `mockReset`), or other tests that use local storage may fail.

The tested code:

```
const someFunction = () => {
  const localStorageKeys = Object.keys(localStorage)
  console.log('localStorageKeys', localStorageKeys)
  localStorage.removeItem('whatever')
}
```

The test:

```
describe('someFunction', () => {
  it('should remove some item from the local storage', () => {
    const _localStorage = {
      foo: 'bar', fizz: 'buzz'
    }

    Object.setPrototypeOf(_localStorage, {
      removeItem: jest.fn()
    })

    const mock = jest.spyOn(global, 'localStorage', 'get')

    try {
      mock.mockReturnValue(_localStorage)
      someFunction()
      expect(_localStorage.removeItem).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
      expect(_localStorage.removeItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith('whatever')
    } finally {
      mock.mockRestore()
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object to achieve `Object.keys()` ability.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
class FakeLocalStorage {
  store = {};
  setItem = (key, val) => (this.store[key] = val);
  getItem = (key) => this.store[key];
  removeItem = (key) => {
    delete this.store[key];
  };
  clear = () => (this.store = {});
}

let fakeLocalStorage = new FakeLocalStorage();
fakeLocalStorage = new Proxy(fakeLocalStorage, {
  ownKeys: (target) => {
    return Object.keys(target.store);
  },
  getOwnPropertyDescriptor(k) {
    return {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    };
  },
});

(async function test() {
  fakeLocalStorage.setItem('name', 'TS');
  fakeLocalStorage.setItem('age', 23);
  const keys = Object.keys(fakeLocalStorage);
  console.log('keys:', keys);
})();
```

The execution results:

```sh
keys: [ 'name', 'age' ]
```